# How can I update all NULL fields in a table to empty strings SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called dbo.authors and would like to update all null fields in this table to an empty string.  (Basically do the exact opposite of this: [How can I update all empty string fields in a table to be null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428999/how-can-i-update-all-empty-string-fields-in-a-table-to-be-null))

I've tried this and I get a 'command succesful' message but it doesn't update the null field to an empty string.

```
CREATE PROC resetNullFields 
(@TableName NVARCHAR(100))        
AS    

CREATE TABLE #FieldNames    
(    
pk INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,    
Field NVARCHAR(1000) NULL    
);    

INSERT INTO #FieldNames    
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 

DECLARE @maxPK INT;    
SELECT @maxPK = MAX(PK) FROM #FieldNames    

DECLARE @pk INT;    
SET @pk = 1    

DECLARE @dynSQL NVARCHAR(1000) 

WHILE @pk <= @maxPK    
BEGIN    

 DECLARE @CurrFieldName NVARCHAR(100);    
 SET @CurrFieldName = (SELECT Field FROM #FieldNames WHERE PK = @pk)    

    -- update the field null to empty string here:

    SET @dynSQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' + @CurrFieldName + ' ='' '' where' + @CurrFieldName + '= null'  
    EXEC (@dynSQL)

 SELECT @pk = @pk + 1    
END    

exec resetNullFields authors;
go
```

Comment: What about numeric and date columns? Do you have any of those, and if so, what do you want to put there?

Comment: In your UPDATE statement, you need a SPACE after the WHERE clause.

Comment: I would like to put an empty space in a date or numeric column (if possible)

Comment: @Eric It is impossible to put an empty space into date and numeric columns. They can only contain dates/numbers and NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end of the query string you have this:

```
' ='' '' where' + @CurrFieldName + '= null'
```

There's (at least) four problems in just that little section. One is that you're missing whitespace around the field name. Another is that it fails to account for problematic column names. Another is that you can't do a null comparison like that. Finally, the code would add a single space, rather than an empty string. Do it like this instead:

```
' ='''' where [' + @CurrFieldName + '] IS null'
```

Looking through the code, I doubt that's the only problem, though. At minimum, you want to also be sure you're only looking at string-type columns (varchar, char, nvarchar, nchar, etc). You won't be able to do this for number (numeric, int, float, etc) and temporal (date, datetime, etc) columns. If you want to get rid of NULL values in those kinds of columns, you'll need to pick other defaults.

I also question the wisdom of doing this at all. It's usually not a good idea (though there are a small number of scenarios where it can make sense).

Comment: I have modified the end of the query string with your suggestion.
Also, all my columns are of string-type columns.  It is still not working.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help very much. Have you tried adding a print statement to output your constructed sql for each record? That would help you find the issue.

Comment: You can also use `' ='''' where ' + QUOTENAME(@CurrFieldName) + ' IS null'`.  The advantage is that it will properly escape any quote identifiers.

Comment: What I meant by 'Not working' was that I get a 'Command(s) completed successfully' message after executing the procedure and yet I still have 'Null' values in my table.  I've added a print (@dynSQL) under the Set @dynSQL line and I don't see the constructed SQL for each record.

Comment: If you're not seeing any print statements, then it's not entering the while loop. Make sure the #FieldNames table is actually getting data.